Interesting posts for you?
These are the tags that I'm interested in:



And these are the interesting posts for me?



Really? Except for one occurrence of python, there's nothing about those posts that draws my attention. And actually, that makes me less engaged with SO. You should really fix this.
Usually I think I'm on the wrong page, and then click on HOME, until I notice that doesn't change anything.
Going to one of my watched tags has also become inconvenient, because by default, it shows only 7 of them in alphabetical order and not in the order of my preference.



So, yes, Stack Overflow UI designers, UX engineers or whatnot, you are annoying and slowly losing one more user.

"the question selection algorithm is the exact same as before" - no, certainly not. The old UI had at least those yellowish questions for tags that I watched. There are no yellow questions any more.

"the question selection algorithm is the exact same as before" means the algorithm didn't change. But the highlighting did change. So, the list would be the same before and after. I never found the "interesting" questions to actually be interesting. And I've seen several reports after the front page change of people stating the same but somehow blaming the update for it. Yet, they really only lost the highlighting. Meaning the list was probably never fit for them anyway, they just now found out.

What is this "Yellow" thing you speak of?

@user4581301 the highlight for watched tags - when a question has any tags you watch, their background is changed so they stand out. Example (in high contrast dark mode)

Ah ha. Not sure I formally watch any tags. I just bookmarked tagged/c%2b%2b and use that as my "home" page for Stack Overflow.

I think it is safe to say that even IF the algorithm is finally improved and deployed... having a tag such as "windows" in the list is going to immediately derail it. It makes no sense to watch a tag which casts a net that wide.

@Gimby: well, at least better (for me) than azure, js, react, docker, elasticcloud which I get now. If I see Windows in the tag, I will at least recognize that I chose that.
